# Prove that $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis

The ceiling function $\lceil\cdot\rceil:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as $\lceil x\rceil=\min\{n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\wedge n\ge x\}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then how to prove that the ceiling function is well-defined? I've come up with some proofs about this, but I think my approach is not good enough. And I'm curious about how other people would prove this fact, using what theorems of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$. (I'm not a student major in these courses, so it's not a homework.)

Answer (score 2):

The set $S_x=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\ge x\}$ is non empty by the Archimedean property (given any real number $x$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x<n$) and bounded below by $x$, so it has an infimum $m$, by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$.

If $m\notin S_x$, then there exists $n\in S_x$ such that $m<n<m+\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $0<n-m<1$, which is absurd being $n-m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Actually, completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ can be avoided, by just using well ordering of the natural numbers.

Let $n_0$ be an integer such that $n_0+x>0$: this exists, because by the Archimedean property, there is a positive integer such that $-x<n_0$.

Then the set $T=\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid m\ge n_0+x\}$ is non empty, so it has a minimum $m_0$. Prove that
$$
m_0-n_0=\lceil x\rceil
$$

Comment: Is completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ really relevant here? The minimum is over the integers. The ceiling function for $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is just as well defined as that over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Winther Not necessary, indeed. I'll add a note.

Comment: @egreg Another question, how can you prove the Archimedean property? I saw many textbook proving it using the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. However, $\mathbb{Q}$ also satisfy the Archimedean property.

Comment: In particular, I wonder that can we prove that "$\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above"(which is an equivalent statement of the Archimedenn property) without using any completeness?

Comment: For example, this reference actually use the completeness: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/508F14/Notes/archimedean.pdf
But I wonder if it can be avoided.

Comment: @Eric It depends on how you introduce the real numbers. Indeed, the Archimedean property is a consequence of completeness (but it is weaker).

Comment: Can we find a proof of "$\mathbb{Q}$ satifying the Archimedean property" without referring anything to real numbers?

Comment: @Eric Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers; then $a=bq+r$, for unique integers $q$ and $r$, where $0\le r<b$. Then $a/b<q+1$.